# What is the most Django-appropriate way to combine multiple database columns into one model field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

I have several times come across a want to have a Django model field that comprises multiple database columns, and am wondering what the most Django way to do it would be.

Three use cases come specifically to mind.

1. I want to provide a field that wraps another field, keeping record of whether the wrapped field has been set or not.  A use case for this particular field would be for dynamic configuration.  A new configuration value is introduced, and a view marks itself as dependent upon a configuration value, redirecting if the value isn't set.  Storing whether it's been set yet or not allows for easy indefinite caching of the state.  This also lets the configuration value itself be not-nullable, and the application can ignore any value it might have when unset.
2. I want to provide a money field that combines a decimal (or integer) value, and a currency.
3. I want to provide a file field with a link to some manner of access rule to determine whether the request should include it/a request for it should succeed.

For each of the use cases, there exists a workaround, that in each case seems less elegant.

1. Define the configuration fields as nullable.  This is undesirable for a few reasons: it removes the validity of `NULL` as a value for the configuration itself, so tristates and other use valid cases for `NULL` have to become a pair of fields or a different data type, or an edge case; `null=True` on the fields allows them to be set back to `None` in modelforms and the admin without writing a custom `FormField` for them every time; and every nullable column in a database is arguably bad design.
2. Define the field as a subclass of `DecimalField` with an argument accepting a string, and use that to contribute another field to the model.  (This is what `django-money` does).  Again, this is undesirable: fields are appearing "as if by magic" on the model; and configuring the currency field becomes not obvious.
3. Define the combined file+rule field instead as an entire model, and one-to-one to it from the model where you want to have the field.  This is a solution to all use cases, but again comes with downsides: there's an extra `JOIN` required for every instance of the field - one can imagine a `User` with `profile_picture`, `cv`, `passport`, `private_key` etc.; there's an implicit requirement to `.select_related(*fields)` on every query that would ever want to access the fields; and the layout of the related model is going to have cold data interleaved with hot data all over the place given that it's reused everywhere.

In addition to solution 3., there's also the option to define a mixin factory that produces the multiple fields with matching names and whatever desired properties and methods.  Again this isn't perfect because the user ends up with fields being defined in the model body, but also above that in the inheritance list.

I think the main reason this keeps sending me in circles is because custom Django model fields are always defined in terms of a single base field, because it's done by inheritance.

What is the accepted way to achieve this end?